# Can you use composite z-scores in a repeated measures t-test?

Tags: t-test, composite

Can you use composite z-scores to perform a t-test. If so, can you use a composite z-scores in a repeated measures t-test?

Comment: what do you mean by "composite $z$-score"?

Comment: Four separate items converted to z-scores and summed.

Comment: Then, sure, you can treat this variable the same as you would any other quantitative variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do I have to do anything special with the z-scores for a repeated measure design? Maybe I should calculate the z-scores based on the total mean and SD for each variable before separating the data into my before and after groups to avoid getting means of zero across the board?

Comment: I actually became aware of this website because of your post "Calculating Composite Scores of Ability and Other Tests." Oddly when I calculate the means from my composite measure the two groups always seem to be the same distance from the mean like M1=0.76 and M2=-0.76 or M1=1.79 and M2=-1.79. I've tested the composite measure on two different datasets (one between and the other within subject designs). Is it just coincidence that my results turn out this way?

Comment: @Matthew, are you the person who asked this question?  If so, we need to merge your accounts so you can more easily edit and comment on your question.  Please let us know.

Comment: @MatthewEbben I see that you've expressed your comment as a separate question. I've added an answer there: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30838/183

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use composite z-scores when doing a t-test.
If you are doing repeated measures t-test it is essential that you use the same mean and standard deviation across time points to calculate your composite z-scores. Otherwise, any differences over time will cancel out, and the mean of both time points will be zero.

For more information about composite z-scores, see my post on [Calculating Composite Scores of Ability and Other Tests](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/calculating-composite-scores-of-ability.html) . For some reason it has attracted 20 or 30 questions on the topic from various readers.