# Is it typical for group means of composite z-scores to have means with values of the same magnitude but opposite signs?

Tags: mean, standardization, composite, group-differences

I developed a composite score by converting four items to z-scores, then I summed up the z-scores to form a composite measure.

However, when I've calculated means to compare finding for two different groups on a couple datasets using this composite score, the mean scores are the same distance from zero.

For example,

- For one dataset, M1= 0.76 and M2= -0.76
- For anotherdataset M1= 1.34 and M2= -1.34.

Is this typical finding for this type of composite score?

It seems odd to me.

Comment: Could you please describe more precisely how you convert "items" to z-scores?  What kind of data value does an "item" have and how are the four items related?  Why do you provide examples with only two mean scores instead of four?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's normal assuming the sample sizes for your two groups are equal, which if you have repeated measures data then they generally will be.

#### Example with equal group sizes

Here's a simulated example.

```
set.seed(1234)
rawscore <- rnorm(100, 5, 2)
g <- c(rep(0:1, 50))
rawscore <- rawscore + g
Data <- data.frame(g, rawscore)
Data$z <- scale(Data$rawscore)
tapply(Data$z, Data$g, mean)
```

```
##       0       1 
## -0.2159  0.2159
```

- This simulates 100 observations with mean 5 and sd 2.
- And assigns the data to one of two groups (group 0; and group 1)
- I've added `g` to the raw scores to make group one have a systematically higher mean.
- We can then standardise the raw score using the overall mean and standard deviation.
- Now if we look at the mean, we see that the mean in each group is of the same magnitude but opposite sign.

#### Example with unequal group sizes

```
rawscore <- rnorm(100, 5, 2)
g <- c(rep(c(0, 0, 0, 1), 50))
rawscore <- rawscore + g
Data <- data.frame(g, rawscore)
Data$z <- scale(Data$rawscore)
tapply(Data$z, Data$g, mean)
```

```
##        0        1 
## -0.03008  0.09024
```

- This example is the same as above, but has three times as many participants in group 0, and as such the mean for group 0 is reversed and a third of the mean of group 1 in magnitude.